# Illustrator: paste text without formatting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Is it possible to somehow copy and paste text from TEXT-A into TEXT-B and make the pasted text formatted like TEXT-B? It always keeps source formatting. In InDesign apparently it's possible via Edit menu, but not here (I'm working with CS6 on Win7)

Comment: I always paste into a text editor then copy paste into Illustrator to remove formatting.

Comment: I see. It would be nice to be able to do this without that extra step...

Comment: It is possible to scrub the formatting in the clipboard. A script could then call this from illustrator trough a shortcut or button in window etc. Would that suffice?  What OS.

Comment: @joojaa That would be a step faster, indeed. I'm thinking about a solution with AutoHotKey, which could be probably the fastest approach: select text, then press `ctrl-c` (or `win-c`)  and then the text would be cleaned in the clipboard, ready to paste. PS. I work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we could put the Search box to good use and skip the text editor.

- Copy your text as usual
- Ctrl+V to paste here and get rid of formatting

[image]

- Ctrl+A to select it
- Ctrl+C to copy it again
- Paste as usual

[edit]

or better yet, for multi-line copy/pasting

- open the Attributes Panel
- in the flyout menu click on Show Note
- paste it there

[image]

- Ctrl+A to reselect All
- Ctrl+X to Cut (and remove the note from the text frame)
- paste as usual

Comment: Nice approach! Wasn't even aware that such search box exists :) however, it seems to be limited to only 256 characters, although in most of the caseses should be fine.

Comment: Good idea, but only if you have one line of text.

Comment: This is the saddest moment in the whole history of computer science.

Comment: Well at least that search box isn't useless after all.

Comment: Ctl+Alt+V, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont creat a type area and paste the text in work area the text come without formating. Or you can paste in text editor first like notepad ++ and then copy to illustrator type area
I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I use Text Editor, copy the original contents, cut it again and paste it to InDesign. Also, in CS6, you can see a popup while pasting content. You can work around the settings there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take Illustrator document A. Save as a PDF. Open up PDF in Acrobat. Go to edit PDF. Copy and paste text over to document B and source formatting will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was using a clipboard manager 
I am using [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) for Windows and [CopyClip](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/copyclip-clipboard-history/id595191960?mt=12) for Mac 
It's very easy to get around this issue, you just paste the text from the clipboard manager as shown in this video.
https://youtu.be/aF1RvAUEyHc